# Как распарсить yml.xml

Tags: yml

Есть выгрузка с сайта yml.xml.
Как его распарсить, ковырял exelем, не получается много есть одинаковых тегов.
Хотелось бы получить в итоге столбцы с значениями параметров, если например тега `<pictre>` два, то вставить их через какойто разделитель.

```html
</offer>
<offer id="37056" available="true" type="vendor.model">
  <vendor>Conte</vendor>
  <typePrefix>Бюстгальтер купальный</typePrefix>
  <country_of_origin>Беларусь</country_of_origin>
  <url>https://conteshop.com.ua/conte/byustgalter-kupalnyy-bikini-balkonet-viki-chernyy?utm_source=skidochnik&amp;utm_medium=cpc</url>
  <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
  <categoryId>2101</categoryId>
  <delivery>true</delivery>
  <description>Черный однотонный лиф с глубоким декольте – соблазнительный элемент пляжного образа. Идеально подходит девушкам с пышной грудью. Фиксируется завязками на шее и застежкой на спине.</description>
  <model>Бикини-балконет VIKI</model>
  <param name="Короткое описание">Бюстгальтер купальный женский VIKI, р.70(C), черный</param>
  <param name="Материал">полиамид 85%; эластан 15%</param>
  <param name="Размер">70(C),75(C),80(C),75(D),80(D),70(D)</param>
  <param name="Цвет">черный</param>
  <price>459</price>
  <oldprice>799</oldprice>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/7/27d12a9e04dfd41194713f39fc450fe4.jpg</picture>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/6/8/688fce4dc53d83d6c00626e88dadda9f.jpg</picture>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/c/ec5847909d6aebd23200f9d063d91031_1.jpg</picture>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/e/a/ea9928fd45ada1a1308b264970247b4e_1.jpg</picture>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/9/c/9c9ec5506c03c82ad19d6b7682db1ee8.jpg</picture>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/7/27d12a9e04dfd41194713f39fc450fe4_1.jpg</picture>
</offer>
<offer id="11729" available="true" type="vendor.model">
  <vendor>Conte</vendor>
  <typePrefix>Носки хлопковые женские</typePrefix>
  <country_of_origin>Беларусь</country_of_origin>
  <url>https://conteshop.com.ua/conte/noski-hlopkovye-jenskie-active-dekor-rezinka-seryy?utm_source=skidochnik&amp;utm_medium=cpc</url>
  <currencyId>UAH</currencyId>
  <categoryId>1342</categoryId>
  <delivery>true</delivery>
  <description>Укороченные спортивные женские носки из хлопка, однотонные с контрастной декоративной отделкой по краю резинки.</description>
  <model>ACTIVE (декор. резинка)</model>
  <param name="Короткое описание">Носки хлопковые женские ACTIVE (декор. резинка) 12С-32СП, p. 23, серый, рис. 035</param>
  <param name="Материал">хлопок 72%; полиамид 25;5%; эластан 2;5%</param>
  <param name="Размер">23,25</param>
  <param name="Цвет">белый-бирюза,светло-серый,белый-бледно-бирюзовый,темно-серый,белый-малиновый,белый-салатовый,серый,белый-светло-голубой,белый-сиреневый</param>
  <price>49</price>
  <market_category>Одежда, обувь и аксессуары/Женская одежда/Белье и купальники/Носки</market_category>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/3/d/3ddd391e15a0fcbe75998afa5232b756.jpg</picture>
  <picture>https://conteshop.com.ua/media/catalog/product/cache/11/image/371x496/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/2/1/218021dfced8580588b5b14af2c93106.jpg</picture>
</offer>
```

Comment: Так всё-таки yml или xml? Покажите пример файла

Comment: YML я так понимаю это какой-то стандарт для файлов выгрузки. фаил называется yml.xml   B таких offer там 1630 штук

Comment: Для начала с каким ЯП вы работаете? Исходя из этого, выбираете библиотеку/встроенную функцию и начинаете парсить файлы.